# Array out of boundries

Tags: java, arrays

I can't figure out why is the array out of its borders, eclipes says the problem is at  line 15

> int d = array[1] - array[0];

```
import java.util.*;

public class Arrays1 {
    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = reader.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[N];
        boolean right = true;
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number for array");
            array[i] = reader.nextInt();
        }
        int d = array[1] - array[0];
        if ((array[N]-1)%d !=0)
        {
            right = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: **Never** trust user Input!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like that:

```
public class Main {

    static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = reader.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[N];
        boolean right = true;
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter number for array");
            array[i] = reader.nextInt();
        }
        int d = array[1] - array[0];
        if ((array[N-1])%d !=0)
        {
            right = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Have a look at this part:

```
if ((array[N-1])%d !=0)
```

You were doing: `if ((array[N]-1)%d !=0)`

Btw, is aways a problem to trust the scan, you will need several validations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you read the bounds of your array from the reader, it may be 0 or 1. To ensure it is big enough, you can try something like:

```
   if(N > 1) {
        int d = array[1] - array[0];
        if ((array[N]-1)%d !=0)
        {
            right = false;
        }
   }
```

If it has to be bigger than 1 for you application to work, you could enforse this contraint right at the beginning:

```
int N = reader.nextInt();
if(N <= 1) {
   System.out.println("N must be bigger than 1");
   System.exit(1); // exit with error code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to validate the user input before you read your `Array` items, as the user may enter **1** for example when he is prompted for the array size thus there well be only one item in the array and accessing the item in second index (1 as it 0 based) will result in an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Arrays1 {
  static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = reader.nextInt();
    while (N < 2) {
      System.out.println("Enter a valid size for the array");
      N = reader.nextInt();
    }
    int[] array = new int[N];
    boolean right = true;
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter number for array");
      array[i] = reader.nextInt();
    }
    int d = array[1] - array[0];
    if ((array[N]-1)%d !=0)
    {
      right = false;
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>As a side note, pay attention to follow Java naming conventions as of the camelCase,so identifiers may begin with lowercase character not upper ones such as for **int N** which should be **int n**.</sup>